# Reply from NodeJS server to twilio autopilot assistant's message

Tags: node.js, twilio

I am receiving data from twilio autopilot assistant on a webhook. My NodeJS server is hosted on AWS. I want respond from the server as if the assistant is responding. I have not found anything on how to respond to the SMS as if the assistant is reply.

Answer (score 1):

You would use the Autopilot Say action for that purpose. You will return a JSON object to Twilio Autopilot from your Node application.

Here is an example of a [Simple Response](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/function-library/simple-response) using Twilio Functions (Node).

[Say](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/actions/say)

Comment: This is for Twilio functions but I am not using Twilio functions. I am hosting my NodeJS on AWS. Will it work with that?

Comment: @Alan How do you access your Autopilot Bot's memory from a Autopilot POST webhook request to your NodeJS application?

Comment: Nevermind, I worked it out.
For anyone else with this issue:

req.body.Memory